# What is the data structure for real-time searching for the most suitable (least diverged) text mask for given input

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, masking

Given:

1. A constant original array of string (~5k elements)

```
[
    "595(###)###-###",
    "974-####-####",
    "262-#####-####",
    "40-##-###-####",
    "381-##-###-####",
    ...
]
```

The #-sign means "any digit". All # signs are located only after digits part, but can contain (), space or - sign

2. a user-typed string that could be like one of these

```
[
    "1 (23"
    "7 950 745 88 15",
    "7 (950) 745-88-15",
    "7 (950) 745 88-15",
    "79507458815"
]
```

I need to find the most suitable mask in array (1) for given string (2).
The solution must fit in O(log n) in CPU, and, O(n^2) in memory.

My idea of suitability is based on Damerau–Levenshtein distance, but it punishes for every difference with #-sign, although it shouldn't.

I tried fuzzy search and BK-tree, but it works way too slow, takes about 100 ms to compute.

Comment: Damerau–Levenshtein distance looks fine to me, you just have to modify the cost function to handle '#' like a match (=0 cost). But this is not O(log n)

Comment: @MrSmith42 is there a possible way of "caching" this in a fancy data structure?

Comment: @MrSmith42 could you please give me details? I managed to build my own getSimilarity function, it returns the score of how similar the strings are. and when I sort the array, it shows exactly what I want. I tried to think how to implement the K-D tree to store it, but didnt manage myself. Also, Its important to say that the value is from 1 to 17 symbols exactly, and the dictionary of value is quite narrow, 0-9, space, (, ), and -. I think it can be used to optimize the storage?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use so-called Patricia tree

the final structure (JSON) is

```
{
    "7": {
       "12": {
         "$value": "712###########",
       },
       "13": {
         "4": {
            ...
         }
       },
       "95#": {
         "$value": "795###########",
       },
       "maxPrefixLength": "3",
     ...
    },
    "maxPrefixLength": "1",
    ...
}
```

The algorithm is (JS)

```
const getMaskedKeys = (obj: any) =>
  Object.keys(obj).filter((e) => e.includes("#"));

const findValues = (node: TrieNode) => {
  let currentNode = node;

  const values: string[] = [];

  while (currentNode) {
    values.push(currentNode.$value);
    currentNode = currentNode["#"];
  }

  return values;
};

const getObjectKeyByPath = (obj: any, path: string[]) => {
  let result = obj;

  for (const p of path) {
    result = result[p];
  }

  return result;
};

export function createMaskTree(maskRows: string[]) {
  const uniqueRows = [...new Set(maskRows)];

  const masks = uniqueRows.map((mask, i) => {
    const key = mask.replace(/[ +()\-]/g, "");

    return [key, mask];
  });

  masks.sort((a, b) => (a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1));

  const trie = Trie.create({
    wildcard: "#",
  });

  masks.forEach(([key, mask]) => {
    trie.insert(key, mask);
  });

  optimize(trie.tree);

  return trie.tree as TrieNode;
}

export function searchMask(
  cleanValue: string,
  root: TrieNode,
  debug = false
): string[] {
  let matches: string[] = [];
  let path: string[] = [];
  let key = cleanValue;

  const q: TrieNode[] = [root];

  while (q.length) {
    const currentNode = q.shift()!;

    if (debug) {
      console.log(
        "Search Iteration. Key:",
        key,
        "Path:",
        path,
        "level:",
        path.length
      );
    }

    let l = currentNode.maxPrefixLength || key.length;
    // let l = key.length;

    let isEmpty = true;

    // Search for existing prefixes and recursively descend
    while (l--) {
      const prefix = key.substring(0, l + 1);
      if (debug) {
        console.log("prefix=", prefix, "path=", path);
      }
      if (currentNode[prefix]) {
        isEmpty = false;
        path.push(prefix);
        if (debug) {
          console.log(prefix, "found in tree! current path:", path);
        }
        q.push(currentNode[prefix]);
        const suffix = key.substring(l + 1);
        key = suffix;
      }
    }

    if (isEmpty) {
      let l = currentNode.maxPrefixLength || key.length;
      while (l--) {
        const prefix = key.substring(0, l) + "#";

        if (debug) console.log("     mask prefix=", prefix);

        if (currentNode[prefix] && currentNode[prefix].$value) {
          matches.push(...findValues(currentNode[prefix]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!matches.length) {
    if (debug)
      console.log(
        "No matches found without mask. Trying again with mask only!"
      );

    const last = path.pop();
    key = last + key;

    let currentNode: TrieNode = root;

    let isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
      currentNode = getObjectKeyByPath(root, path);
      const keys = getMaskedKeys(currentNode);

      if (debug) {
        console.log(
          "Mask search Iteration. Key:",
          key,
          "Path:",
          path,
          "level:",
          path.length,
          "currentNode keys:",
          keys
        );
      }

      let l = currentNode.maxPrefixLength || key.length;
      while (l--) {
        const prefix = key.substring(0, l) + "#";

        if (debug) console.log("     mask prefix=", prefix);

        if (currentNode[prefix] && currentNode[prefix].$value) {
          matches.push(...findValues(currentNode[prefix]));
        }
      }

      let pathPart = path.pop();
      key = pathPart + key;

      if (currentNode === root && !path.length) {
        isRunning = false;
      }
    }
  }

  return matches;
}
```